# github server verification failed

Tags: git, github

I've been receiving this error today while doing the git push command, this is the very first time this error shows up and I've been using github for months now!

```
$ git push -u origin add_scope_to_delay_system
error: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none while accessing https://github.com/jhx/(repository name goes here).git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I tried using this solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gitlabhq/6OHYFpsJQaM/SI8-XdxY70EJ however it did not work. The solution was to add

```
[http]
sslVerify = false
[https]
verify = false
```

to .gitconfig

**Update**

This issue went away by it self, unfortunately i do not know what started nor ended it.

Comment: So did you solve it, or…? (And that’s not a very safe solution…)

Comment: It did not work, and i have not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

github was experiencing some issues earlier today as they launched government.github.com. The site should be functioning normally now.